# Adding to the back of a Circular Singly linked list without a tail pointer

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment for class and getting some direction would be great. I am implementing Java code for a Circular singly linked list and we have to add to the back of the list in O(1) time but the only instance variables we have for our class are the head pointer and the size. Usually I would just loop through til I find the null next pointer but that would not be O(1), so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Are you allowed to change how the data structure is linked? If you can't do this, you won't be able to perform this operation in O(1). If you can, you have two options: change the direction of the link pointer (next to previous) or use double links (next and previous).

Comment: @davidbuzatto it's singly linked so we have no previous or tail pointer. I think I figured out how to go about it using a new node and rearranging the data and pointers at the head.